# CSS animation of an element's background-image size on window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want an effect like this (yellow logo on the left hand side):

http://startbootstrap.com/templates/agency/

Thaw when you scroll window its smoothly shrinks in size.

For my own project, i have a div which receives a background-image.

```
<div class='logo-image'></div>
```

Then I tried to animate it using CSS3-Transitions like this:

```
.logo-image-scroll
{
    background-size: 150px auto !important;

}
.logo-image
{
    background-image: url(../../asset/image/logo-large.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 301px 80px;
    background-position: center right;
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-transition-property: background;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-transition-property: background;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-transition-property: background;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -ms-transition-property: background;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
```

I then add the `logo-image-scroll` class on window scroll using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(window.scrollY < 20)
        {
            $(".nav-container").removeClass("fixed");
            $(".nav-container .logo-image").removeClass("logo-image-scroll");
        }
        else
        {
            $(".nav-container").addClass("fixed");
            $(".nav-container .logo-image").addClass("logo-image-scroll");
        }
    });

});
```

And I expect it to work, but it does not work though. What should I edit in the CSS or HTML for it to work?

Comment: First of all, you should use `$(this).scrollTop()`, as `scrollY` is not cross-browser.

Comment: Secondly, your CSS transition seems to work -> **http://jsfiddle.net/gv2cxueL/**  
so what you really want is probably not to remove the original class, but just add and remove the second class

Comment: it'll animate smoother if you replace 'auto' with actual pixels or use %

Comment: thanks I got the point